# TRIE data structure implementation in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, trie

I have written a simple code to implement a trie data structure in c++. But when I run this program, it gives segmentation error as an output.
Kindly please correct me, where i have been wrong.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

struct trienode {
    struct trienode * child[26];
    bool isEnd;

    trienode()
    {
        isEnd = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            child[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
};

struct trienode * root;

void insert_str(string &s, int n)
{
    trienode * curr = root;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int index = s[i] - 'a';
        if(curr -> child[index] == NULL)
        {
            curr -> child[index] = new trienode();
        }
        else
        {
            curr = curr -> child[index];
        }
    }

    curr -> isEnd = true;
}

int main()
{
    string s1 = "yash";
    insert_str(s1, 4);
}
```

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h` is a big no as well as `using namespace std;`. Besides, I don't see memory allocated to the root node.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocated any memory for your root node.

Normally you would have a separate class to handle the trie as a whole. It can then allocate the root node.

```
class trie
{
public:
    trie()
    {
        root = new trienode();
    }
    void insert_str(string &s, int n)
    {
        ...
    }
private:
    trienode* root;
};

int main()
{
    trie t;
    string s1 = "yash";
    t.insert_str(s1, 4);
}
```